Wix5 Install VC Redistributable + Application
I want to create an installer with Wix5 that will install VC Redistributable (x86 + x64) and then my application.
There is no documentation on how to do this on Wix5 (or 4 for that matter) and most discussions are decades old and often talk about merge modules which are no longer recommended. The site only references the XML tree structure and this tutorial only shows how to achieve the most trivial task of creating an installer for a single .exe file. The only potential example I found on how to do this was this gist and attempting to build it fails with a Error (active)    WIX0350 The package being validated requires a higher version of Windows Installer than is installed on this machine. Validation cannot continue.
Initially I was creating my installer by having a Package.wxs:
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs">
    <Package Name="Test" Manufacturer="TestManufacturer" Version="1.0.0.0" UpgradeCode="0506dc46-deae-40ef-aed7-c9cd2e7ac08e">
        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="!(loc.DowngradeError)" />
        <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />
        <Feature Id="Main">
            <Files Include="..\TestApp\publish\**"/>
        </Feature>
    </Package>
</Wix>

I thought I could maybe have a Bundle that could contain a Chain that would have ExePackage for the VC Redist and my app package but I found no way to reference it the Chain as it only accepts package groups or bundle packages (neither of which accept packages as children) and the WIX0350 issue still persists:
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs"
  xmlns:bal="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/bal"
  xmlns:util="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/util">
    <Bundle
          Name="TestInstaller"
          Version="1.0.0.0"
          Manufacturer="TestManufacturer"
          AboutUrl="https://test.com/"
          UpgradeCode="01234567-89AB-CDEF-0123-456789ABCDEF">

        <BootstrapperApplication>
            <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication
              LicenseUrl="https://example.net/license.html"
              ShowVersion="yes"
              SuppressOptionsUI="yes"
              Theme="hyperlinkLargeLicense" />
        </BootstrapperApplication>

        <Chain>
            <ExePackage
              Id="VC_REDIST_X86"
              DisplayName="Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable (x86) - 14.40.33810"
              Cache="remove"
              PerMachine="yes"
              Permanent="yes"
              Protocol="burn"
              InstallCondition="VersionNT"
              DetectCondition="(VCRUNTIME_X86_VER &gt;= VCRUNTIME_VER) AND VersionNT"
              InstallArguments="/install /quiet /norestart"
              RepairArguments="/repair /quiet /norestart"
              UninstallArguments="/uninstall /quiet /norestart">
                <ExePackagePayload
                  Name="VC_redist.x86.exe"
                  ProductName="Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable (x86) - 14.40.33810"
                  Description="Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable (x86) - 14.40.33810"
                  Hash="91A6283F774F9E2338B65AA835156854E9E76AED32F821B13CFD070DD6C87E1542CE2D5845BEB5E4AF1DDB102314BB6E0AD6214D896BB3E387590A01EAE0C182"
                  Size="13867304"
                  Version="14.40.33810.0"
                  DownloadUrl="https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/9c69db26-cda4-472d-bdae-f2b87f4a0177/A32DD41EAAB0C5E1EAA78BE3C0BB73B48593DE8D97A7510B97DE3FD993538600/VC_redist.x86.exe" />
            </ExePackage>
        </Chain>
    </Bundle>
</Wix>

What is the correct way of doing this?
